# Can I create a spring-boot webflux server stub with swagger that includes lombok support?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, lombok

I tried both

```xml
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
      <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
</plugin>
```

And

```xml
<plugin>
       <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.34</version>
</plugin>
```

And none work.
I can't find a way (nor a working sample) to do that (generate model files with lombok support).

The webflux is irrelevant to the model, but I mentioned cause both are requirements, and I can't find a sample with both (nor just spring-boot with lombok annotation generation).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

```xml
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <apiPackage>${api.package.to.generate}</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>${model.package.to.generate}modelPackage>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <additionalProperties>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <useLombok>true</useLombok>
                            </additionalProperties>
                            <configOptions>
                                <library>spring-boot</library>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <skipDefaultInterface>true</skipDefaultInterface>
                                <reactive>true</reactive>
                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                    @lombok.NoArgsConstructor;@lombok.AllArgsConstructor;@lombok.Builder
                                </additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.24</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

This configuration works for me and the only problem left now is how to get rid of the ResponseEntity in the response:

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity<GraphBrowseNodeWithRelationships>>
```

But this one will be asked in another question.

Cheers.